# HTTP 400: Bad Request error in ADFS HTTPS Request

Tags: node.js, ssl, https, adfs

I am writing a **Node.js** app and am trying to integrate an ADFS server to get authentication. For that, I am using `wstrust-client`, and using the ADFS Server URL as my endpoint. My code so far is:

```
app.get('/login', function(req, res) {
    trustClient.requestSecurityToken({
        scope: 'https://mycompany.com',
        username: "username",
        password: "password",
        endpoint: 'https://[adfs server]/adfs/services/trust/13/usernamemixed'
    }, function (rstr) {
         // Access the token
        var rawToken = rstr.token;
        console.log('raw: ' + rawToken);
    }, function(error) {
        console.log(error)
    }); 
});
```

I am requesting **https** through `wstrust-client`

My code in `wstrustclient.js` so far is:

```
var req = https.request(post_options, function(res) {
    res.setEncoding('utf8');
    res.on('data', function(data) {
        console.log("Entered res")

        var rstr = {
            token: parseRstr(data),
            response: res,
        };

        callback(rstr);
    }); 
});

req.write(message);
req.end();
req.on('error', function (e) { 
console.log("******************************");
console.log(e);
console.log("******************************");
```

However, it is throwing this error:

```
******************************
{ [Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE]
    stack: 'Error: UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE\n   
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1253:32)\n    
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:91:17)\n    
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:865:10)\n    
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:416:15)\n  
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:231:10)\n  
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:329:25)\n  
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:176:8)\n  
    at write (_stream_readable.js:496:24)\n 
    at flow (_stream_readable.js:506:7)\n    
    at Socket.pipeOnReadable (_stream_readable.js:538:5)' }
    ******************************
    ******************************
    { [Error: read ECONNRESET]
        stack: 'Error: read ECONNRESET\n   
        at errnoException (net.js:846:11)\n  
        at TCP.onread (net.js:508:19)',
        code: 'ECONNRESET',
        errno: 'ECONNRESET',
        syscall: 'read' }
    ******************************
```

When I browse the same endpoint URL in a browser, it throws `HTTP 400: Bad Request`

I know that it's an SSL type error, and that it's from the server-side. However, I don't know why it's throwing the error and what might be wrong server-side. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the OpenSSL manual [here](http://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/verify.html):

> 21 X509_V_ERR_UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE: unable to verify the
>   first certificate no signatures could be verified because the chain
>   contains only one certificate and it is not self signed.

With that in mind, it seems that you may need to sign your certificate.